# Can Power BI's stacked bar chart visualization hide filtered-out value bucket columns?

Tags: charts, powerbi

When creating a stacked bar (or column) chart in Power BI, selecting a name in the visualization's legend highlights all visible portions in each bar/column that match what was selected.  Is there a way to completely hide everything in the chart that isn't highlighted until the selection is cleared?  The Small Multiples feature accomplishes a similar objective for only a single column from my query, which isn't enough unless I create several visuals (or a new measurement, perhaps?).

I am aware of the Manage Relationships tool, however, I am uncertain whether it provides a path forward.  My searches have shown me it is possible to create a different sort order, but that isn't relevant to my objective.

[Initial chart, Highlighted chart (actual result), and two prospective expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpim8.png)

**Update: After learning about unpivoting columns, it was better to unpivot the columns containing dissimilar categories that I am charting out. This made it possible to use the slicer visual, just as AmilaMGunawardana suggested.**

Comment: To achieve this you have to use a slicer with all the categories in it

Comment: I tried a slicer previously, and again just now. However, is there something about its configuration that I don't understand? I see a nested tree of checkboxes, rather than the column names from my query (i.e., which I had placed in the Values/Column Values bucket in the chart visual), and ticking a checkbox hides everything, not just what isn't highlighted.

Comment: Compared to this other question [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Stacked-bar-chart-with-a-legend-hide-unselected-bars/m-p/2108341), I need 13 columns from my query instead of 1 (i.e., Country_Region in that answer), with the column names selectable.  A Slicer or Table is great for just a single column from the query, just not 13. (By the way, I edited the question a little to be clearer.)